# How to split a Rails model file into multiple files (not concerns, not modules, just separate files)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 4 model Foo defined in a single file foo.rb

```
# app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method1
    ...
  end

  def method2
    ...
  end
end
```

Without any type of class re-definition (eg, without refactoring to use traits or concerns for example), I would like to simply *move* some of the code to a new file, foo_more.rb

```
# app/models/foo.rb
require File.expand_path('../foo_more.rb', __FILE__)
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method1
    ...
  end
end

# app/models/foo_more.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method2
    ...
  end
end
```

When I do so, using the require, it works BUT does not re-load in dev't after changes to the code in that file.

Is there a way to tell Rails to re-load that new file in development after code changes?

Comment: Temporary sandboxing is the reason. I want hand a few dozen methods to another developer to revise & refactor, without them stomping through the main model source file at the same time as another developer who is adding new (but unrelated) functionality.

Comment: This is not an invitation for a code review, @jvillian, my question clearly and succinctly states what I want to do. And have done, albeit not with the ability to auto-reload after code changes like I'd prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require_dependency File.expand_path('../foo_more.rb', __FILE__)
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method1
    ...
  end
end

# app/models/foo_more.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method2
    ...
  end
end
```

> require_dependency(file_name, message = "No such file to load --
>   %s")
>
> Interprets a file using mechanism and marks its defined
>   constants as autoloaded. file_name can be either a string or respond
>   to to_path.
>
> Common Usage:
>
> Use this method in code that absolutely needs a certain constant to be
>   defined at that point. A typical use case is to make constant name
>   resolution deterministic for constants with the same relative name in
>   different namespaces whose evaluation would depend on load order
>   otherwise.
>
> I typically use require_dependency when developing a class or module that resides in my rails app, perhaps in the lib/ dir. A normal require statement does not reload my changes, so I use require_dependency in files that reference my newly developed class or module.

[Source](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable/require_dependency)

It should be noted that your miles may vary. Some people experience major slow downs when including a new dependency. I believe this will reload the file every time you call `Foo.all`, `Foo.find(1)`, etc. So, you should probably only do this in development.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. BTW great user name! My favorite goofy TV series, sad they didn't make more of them!